# Linear functional is zero if and only if it maps an absorbing set to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, normed-spaces

I was randomly thinking about how to characterize linear functionals on a NVS when I though of this. Suppose $X$ is a NVS over $\mathbb{F}$, and I have a linear functional $\phi \in X^{*}$.

Then $\phi = 0$ if any only if there exists an absorbing set $D \subset X$ such that $\phi(D) = \{0\}$? By absorbing set, I mean given any $f \in X$, there exists a $\lambda > 0$ such that $f \in \lambda D = \{\lambda g \: | \: g \in D\}$.

$\rightarrow$ If $\phi = 0$, then any nonempty set $D \subset X$, $\phi(D) = \{0\}$, so this is trivial.

$\leftarrow$ Suppose there exists an absorbing set $D \subset X$ with $\phi(D) = \{0\}$.  Then given any $f \in X$, there exists $\lambda > 0$ such that $f \in \lambda D$.

However by linearity of $\phi$: $$\phi(\lambda D) = \phi(\{\lambda g \: | \: g \in D\}) = \{\phi(\lambda g) \: | \: g \in D\} = \{\lambda \phi(g) \: | \: g \in D\} = \lambda \phi(D) = \{0\}.$$ Hence, $\phi(f)=0$.  Since $f \in X$ was arbitrary, $\phi = 0$.

Is there a name for this result?  This seems like a decently nice result to know about albeit extremely simple.

Thanks.

Edit: I also just realized, this implies that $\text{Null} \: \phi$ being a dense subspace in $X$ implies $\phi = 0$, since any absorbing sets have nonempty interior in $X$?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What concept are you asking about?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear, I'm wondering if there's a name for the result that I stated in my post.

Comment: I doubt it, it seems too obvious to have a name.